# How to install flow type correctly for react native@0.46+?

Tags: react-native, flowtype, react-native-0.46

I've googled many sites but cannot found a tutorial that actually works for react-native + flow type.

There was flow installation guide from [react-native@0.22](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.22/docs/getting-started.html) document, but it's gone in [react-native@0.46](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html).

However, it comes up again in [*Running Tests and Contributing*](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/testing.html), I tested to run `npm run flow` but not working, and yet it doesn't say how to make it works. It's possibly been a missing part inside of react-native documentation.

What I need is to run `flow` correctly with react-native. Auto-check `flow` every time I reload the page with `⌘R` would be the best.

Answer (score 7):

I just finished covering half of our project by flow and we use RN 0.44.0.

The tricky part is: do you also want to know errors inside node_modules, someone says those errors are helpful.

Anyway, I disable the error in node_modules, and here is my .flowconfig:

```
[ignore]

<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/.*
<PROJECT_ROOT>/flowLibs.js
.....
[include]

[libs]
./flowLibs.js
.....
[lints]
[options]
```

You should install flow first if you not setup correctly,

```
npm install --save-dev flow-bin
```

and also run this in you project root after install:

```
npm run flow init
```

If `npm run flow init` does not work, just add `"flow": "flow"` in npm scripts.

After init, put my `.flowconfig` in your project `.flowconfig` file.

Then create a js file `flowLibs.js` and if `npm run flow check` cause your any error like `Module_Name. Required module not found`

Write down code in `flowLibs.js`:

```
declare module 'Module_Name' {  declare var exports: any;  };
```

After that, you should be good to go with you project now.

BTW, don't forget add `//@flow` on the top of the file which you want to check type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although it didn't help much, it gives me a direction to find another solution. check if this helps to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/45790088/681830

Comment: Thanks again, you deserve the bounty!

Comment: The unsafe.enable_getters_and_setters option was removed in 0.62.0 (see https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5594).  Including it in .flowconfig will raise an exception

Answer (score 5):

I found flowtype is built in with react-native@0.46+.

For react-native document, I think they should at least tell **flowtype** is already built in. And for the rest document ex: [Testing Your Changes@flow](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/testing.html#flow), it won't work without `flow-bin`, they should mention that too.

To make flowtype of best use, I use it with Visual Studio Code.

Steps:

1. Install `flow-bin` globally, by `npm i flow-bin -g`.
   Make sure your terminal is responsive to command `flow`.
2. Install [vscode flow extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=flowtype.flow-for-vscode).
3. Set vscode workspace preference with `"javascript.validate.enable": false`, to disable default javascript validation, so flow validation can take place.
   To access vscode preference, `ALT+F,P,S` for windows, `⌘+,` for mac.

then you have flowtype installed with visual result with every key stroke:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

Adding Flow to React Native

https://medium.com/react-native-training/getting-started-with-react-native-and-flow-d40f55746809

Hope this helps!

Comment: did you try it? that was for react-native@0.33.0, but now it's react-native@0.46.0+. I tried but failed before post this question. if you tried it with success please let me know how

Comment: Actually i was just about to start with flow and this was the recommendation from a friend who already done it recently. So i thought i would as well recommend it to you.